# Вывод char с помощью printf()

Tags: c++, printf

Нужно вывести строку:

> "ЖЖ"а"ЖЖ"аа"Ж"

используя `printf()`.

Используя `cout` это выглядело бы так :`cout<<"жж"<<а<<"жж"`.

Answer (score 6):

Что именно вы хотите?
Вывести кавычки?

```
printf("\"ЖЖ\"а\"ЖЖ\"аа\"Ж\"");
```

Вывести ЖЖЖ, а между ними строки из переменных `a` и `aa` типа `char*`?

```
printf("ЖЖ%sЖЖ%sЖ",a,aa);
```

Вывести ЖЖЖ, а между ними строки из переменных `a` и `aa` типа `char`?

```
printf("ЖЖ%cЖЖ%cЖ",a,aa);
```

Вывести ЖЖЖ, а между ними символы из переменных `a` и `aa` типа `string`?

```
printf("ЖЖ%sЖЖ%sЖ",a.c_str(),aa.c_str());
```